# What is the probability that a patient going to a GP country dies?

Tags: probability

[image]

Can some one explain How to do this question?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Showing your attempt and indicating where you got stuck helps users of this site write responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability that a person going to a GP dies = (Probability that the GP sent him home)(Probability that on being sent home, a patient dies) + (Probability that the GP did not send him home)(Probability that on not being sent home, a patient dies)

In country A,
$$Probability = 0.9\times0.01 + 0.1\times0.009=0.0099$$

Similarly solve for country B.